# Advice on how to compare string in a text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Could anyone offer any advice how to compare string from a text file to the info pulled from wmi.

```
$GCard = (Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller").Name
$DriverModel = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\Quadro473.81.txt"

foreach ($Line in $DriverModel)
{

if($Line -like "*$MyCard*")
    {
        write-host "Quadro" 
    }
}
```

The text file (Quadro473.81.txt) is as following.

```
UDA Package name: QuadroWeb Public Disk1

{"NSD":{"State":"0"},"DCH":{"State":"1"}}


nv_disp.inf:
    DEV_0FF3 "NVIDIA Quadro K420"
    DEV_0FF9 "NVIDIA Quadro K2000D"
    DEV_0FFA "NVIDIA Quadro K600"
    DEV_0FFD "NVIDIA NVS 510"
    DEV_0FFE "NVIDIA Quadro K2000"
    DEV_0FFF "NVIDIA Quadro 410"
    DEV_1021 "NVIDIA Tesla K20Xm"
    DEV_1022 "NVIDIA Tesla K20c"
    DEV_1023 "NVIDIA Tesla K40m"
    DEV_1024 "NVIDIA Tesla K40c"
    DEV_1026 "NVIDIA Tesla K20s"
    DEV_1027 "NVIDIA Tesla K40st"
    DEV_1028 "NVIDIA Tesla K20m"
    DEV_1029 "NVIDIA Tesla K40s"
```

The card in the machine report back as NVIDIA Quadro K420

I am trying to work out how to match the string from the video controller name to the list from the drivermodels and have it output the word quadro if it matches.
I would just need to match the model that appears in quotes.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-match` to search through the array of strings returned by `Get-Content` and have it output `"Quadro"` when found inside your `if` statement.

```
$GCard       = (Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller").Name
$DriverModel = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\Quadro473.81.txt"
foreach ($GCName in $GCard)
{
    if ($DriverModel -match $GCName) 
    {
        Write-Host -Object "Quadro"
    }
}
```

Few things to cover when using `-match` comparison operator.

1. When used against an array, it will act as a filter and return the line that was matched against `$GCard`.
2. It's underlying search pattern it uses are regular expressions.

   - So, if your call to `(Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller").Name` returned a value that has special characters, they would have to be escaped.

Since it returns the line it matches, it will evaluate the condition to "*true*" executing your block of code.

**EDIT**: Given that there could be multiple return values in `$GCard`, using a loop you can compare each line with `$DriverModel`.

Comment: One of the issue i think is happening is the $DriverModel sees the line as

`code DEV_0FF3 "NVIDIA Quadro K420"`code

Which wont match NVIDIA Quadro K420 and im not sure how i would go about only picking the text between the quotes.

Comment: @unitechie, what is the issue? `code DEV_0FF3 "NVIDIA Quadro K420"` indeed matches `NVIDIA Quadro K420`.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry you mentioned it in point 2, (Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller").Name returns NVIDIA Quadro K420 but it doesnt seem to match, but im not sure why, a string of "NVIDIA Quadro K420" works

Comment: Can only see an issue if there's a trailing white space you need to trim, or an extra line. Does that call return more than 1 value? Can you post the results of `(Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller").Name`, and `$driverModel -match (Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller").Name; $Matches`?

Comment: (Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller").Name returns`code`NVIDIA Quadro K420 Microsoft Remote Display Adapter`code`
I'm not sure how to run 
`code` $driverModel -match (Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller").Name; $Matches `code` do i need to put it anywhere in particular, sorry im a novice

Comment: that's the issue, it returns 2 values. `NVIDIA Quadro K420`, and `NVIDIA Quadro K420`. Use `@(Get-WmiObject "Win32_Videocontroller")[0].Name` instead.

Comment: That works great thank you. Is there a way to check against all the values

Comment: I have found some device have the cards listed in different orders

Comment: @unitechie, yup. The solution would just be using a loop, see my updated answer.

Comment: Anytime, glad to help!